# Form submit with query params

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple html form where I am trying to do a GET. I have few parameters in there that serve as query strings on submit. Here is the codepen: [form example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KrVYBq)

When I submit the form, the action url becomes`https://www.foo.com/?name=abc&age=20&homepage=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fhomepage`.

When I don't give value for any one of the parameters (ex:name) in the form and submit, the url does not exclude the empty values and instead generates `&name=&age=20`.

Please advise if there is a way to have the action url not take the empty values on submit.

```
<form name="employeeForm" id="theForm" action="https://www.foo.com" method="get">
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b> Name: </b></td>
      <td><input name="name" id="name" value="abc" /><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b> Age: </b></td>
      <td><input name="age" id="age" value="20" /><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b> Homepage: </b></td>
      <td><input name="homepage" id="homepage" value="http://localhost:8080/homepage" /><br/><br/></td>
    </tr>

  </table><br/>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just handle it on the server as you are supposed to or ajax and remove empty fields

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that we cannot do that with plain HTML. But it is quite easy with javascript.

[This page](https://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-empty-fields-get-form/) shares a snippet which is pretty useful:
(It uses jQuery but you can easily adapt it with plain javascript)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // Remove empty fields from GET forms
  $("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").filter(function(){ return !this.value; }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return true; // ensure form still submits
  });

  // Un-disable form fields when page loads, in case they click back after submission
  $( "form" ).find( ":input" ).prop( "disabled", false );

}
```

Comment: No problem - please do not QUOTE the code, just indent 4 spaces